# Ubuntu 11.10 Cron Job fails With - Not Found

Tags: ubuntu, cron, command

I have a script that is supposed to run hourly. It was working fine for a while and then it seemed to stop working after some system updates were applied. At that point it stopped working and presented the error below in /tmp/greatscript.log

`/bin/sh: /home/administrator/greatscript.sh: not found`

Here is the crontab. Really basic, it should work no problem.

`2 * * * * /home/administrator/greatscript.sh >/tmp/greatscript.log 2>&1`

Here's where it gets really weird, I just realized that if administrator is logged in, the cron fires and the script works great. But if administrator is logged out:

`/bin/sh: /home/administrator/greatscript.sh: not found`

Comment: Did you install ubuntu with an encrypted home directory? What is the output of the mount command when administrator is logged in.

Comment: The home directory is encrypted!

Answer (score 2):

Move the script to some unencrypted location like /usr/local/bin/.